# When I transform my c program in a daemon rsh stay blocked in ubuntu system manager

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, daemon, rsh

I have a c program that launched by system call rsh in this way

```
   system(" rsh -l $DTT $CTT './script.sh' ");
```

$DTT and $CTT are enviornment variable where i load in them the user and host name strings

when the c program is normal, the rsh work good, but when i trasform the c program in a daemon and next I execute it, the process rsh stay locked in the ubuntu system manager and waste a lot of CPU resources, rsh work at half, it execute the operation buty it stay blocked.

The code for transform my c program that use rsh is this below.

```
      pid_t process_id = 0;
   pid_t sid = 0;

   //Crea processo figlio
   process_id = fork();


   // Indica il fallimento della fork()
   if (process_id < 0)
   {
        printf("fork failed!\n");

        // ritorna fallimento nello stato di uscita
        exit(1);
   }


   // PROCESSO PADRE. Occore ucciderlo.
   if (process_id > 0)
   {
       printf("process_id of child process %d \n", process_id);

       // ritorna successo nello stato di uscita
        exit(0);
   }

   //unmask the file mode
   umask(0);

   //setta nuova sessione
   sid = setsid();

   if(sid < 0)
   {
       // Return failure
       exit(1);
   }




   // Chiude gli sdandard INPUT,OUTPUT e di ERRORE stdin. stdout and stderr
   close(STDIN_FILENO);
   close(STDOUT_FILENO);
   close(STDERR_FILENO);
```

PROBLEM SOLVED! I redirect the standard output in a file and rsh don't give me any problems!

Comment: What are some examples of DTT and CTT?

Comment: $DTT and $CTT are enviornment variable where i load in them the user and host name strings for example $DTT = alex , $CTT = brandollo

Comment: Can you confirm where it is locked? Is it possible that your program somehow expects a real environment which is not there when you fork?  Does your daemon take all CPU when you run it not from rsh but some other way?  More research, please...

Comment: i call rsh trought system call    system(" rsh -l $DTT $CTT './script.sh' ");       when i control the system manager i see the istance of rsh e when i pass the ointer of mouse i can see the entire call of rsh precedently done that consume a lot of CPU resources.

Comment: I find the problem but i don't know how fix it. The problem is the standard otput that when is close rsh locked and consume CPU resource....